# Document asking to be checked out after checking out

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, document-library, event-receivers

I'm updating a file that contains versioning and previously it stated that the document requires checking out to edit so I run the following code that results with the same error:

```
if (oCurrent.File.CheckOutType.ToString() == "None")
{
    oCurrent.File.CheckOut();
    oCurrent["Tasks Generated"] = "true";
    oCurrent.File.CheckIn("Automated Tasks Generated by Event Handler");
    oCurrent.Update();

    GenerateTasksForNewDocument(oCurrent, ocollCirculation);
}
```

> The file "../sample.txt"
>   is not checked out.  You must first check out this document before
>   making changes.

In addition, when changing the code to the following, I get a similar error:

```
oCurrent.SystemUpdate();
```

> The file International Standards/sample2.txt has been modified by
>   ..\matt on 21 Apr 2015 15:09:26 +0100

How can I get around this as I'm checking the document out already?

Let me know if you need any more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating the item before checking it back in.

```
if (oCurrent.File.CheckOutType.ToString() == "None")
{
    oCurrent.File.CheckOut();
    oCurrent["Tasks Generated"] = "true";
    oCurrent.Update();
    oCurrent.File.CheckIn("Automated Tasks Generated by Event Handler");        

    GenerateTasksForNewDocument(oCurrent, ocollCirculation);
}
```

Comment: that's done it. can't believe I missed the logic with that. thank you.